# How to display some text nodes in XSLT but not others

Tags: xml, xslt

I need to display the text for a given node, while suppressing the text for the child node. I tried to handle this by creating an empty template for the child node, but it didn't work. How to suppress the text of a child node?

Here is the XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<document>
    <item name="The Item">
        <richtext>
            <pardef/>
            <par def="20">
                <run>This text should </run>
                <run>be displayed.
                    <popup><popuptext>This text should not be displayed.</popuptext></popup>
                </run>
            </par>
        </richtext>
    </item>
</document>
```

Here is my stylesheet:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">
   <xsl:output indent="yes" method="html"/>
   <xsl:template match="/*">
        <html>
            <body>
                <table border="1">
                        <xsl:apply-templates/>
                </table>
            </body>
        </html>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="item">
        <tr>
            <td><xsl:value-of select="@name"/></td>
            <td>
                <xsl:apply-templates/>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="run">
         <xsl:value-of select="." separator=""/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="popuptext" />

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to change your `select="."` to `select="text()"`...

```
<xsl:template match="run">
  <xsl:value-of select="text()"/>
</xsl:template>
```

Also, since you don't do an apply-templates from `run`, the template matching `popuptext` isn't needed.

Answer (score 1):

If you only want to display the text for the `run` element, use `select="text()"`:

```
<xsl:template match="run">
     <xsl:value-of select="text()" separator=""/>
</xsl:template>
```

If you use `select="."` it selects all of the content of the `run` element, which includes the content of its child elements.

I'm not sure this is 100% the best way to do it, but it does prevent the child element content of `run` from being displayed in your specific case.

My full version of the stylesheet is:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">
   <xsl:output indent="yes" method="html"/>
   <xsl:template match="/*">
        <html>
            <body>
                <table border="1">
                        <xsl:apply-templates/>
                </table>
            </body>
        </html>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="item">
        <tr>
            <td><xsl:value-of select="@name"/></td>
            <td>
                <xsl:apply-templates/>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="run">
         <xsl:value-of select="text()" separator=""/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="popuptext" />

</xsl:stylesheet>
```